# Не получается запустить бота через консоль. Да и вообще не получается

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MckiP.)
Не получается запустить бота Дискорд, помогите пожалуйста. В консоли выдает ошибку(см.фото)
Надеюсь на вашу помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]jpg

Answer (score 2):

В окне терминала прекрасно видно, что вам необходимо установить модуль discord.

```
pip install discord
```

Comment: а как его установить? я просто еще зеленый в этом и прошу помощи

Comment: @Владислав Кругляков вам бы книжки почитать для начала,основы языка познать.начинать сразу с бота крайне не рационально.